# How to pass mongodb 'or' & 'and' query in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I pass mongodb 'or' & 'and' query in node.js

If execute below query in mongodb shell, it works fine

```
> db.data.find({$or:[{"privacy":1},{$and:[{"privacy":3},{"userId":"59b8b9fbb8c53b252be10562"}]}]}).pretty();
```

But now in node.js I want to pass same query as parameter to the model. I have tried so far to pass this parameter is

```
const query = {$or: [ {"privacy": 1}, $and: [{"privacy": 3}, {"userId": "59b8b9fbb8c53b252be10562"}] ] };
```

it throws an error as: **"Error: unknown operator: $or"**

Comment: that also tried but still not working

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot something look at here
try this way

```
 const query = {$or: [ {"privacy": 1}, {$and: [{"privacy": 3}, {"userId": "59b8b9fbb8c53b252be10562"}]} ] };
```

or condition must like this

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

Comment: I tried which u have given. still error: `"Error: unknown operator: $or",`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by posting the query in model
Key I have mentioned in controller and passes that key to the model, then in model I wrote query for that.